# Dockerfile para app python y aws service

Tags: python, docker, aws

me encuentro desarrollando un pequeño proyecto en python (Es mis segundo proyecto en este lenguaje, recientemente ingresé a la industria), el cual consiste en dos bots, uno encargado de publicar información proveniente de una API en un tópico SNS de aws y el otro que debe consumir dicha información a través de una cola SQS suscripta a dicho tópico y almacenar esos datos en S3 bucket. La funcionalidad la tengo corriendo, el problema es que me piden "dockerizar" ambos bots y soy nuevo en esta tecnología. Estoy aprendiendo de la documentación de AWS y de DOCKER pero no me queda claro de que manera interactúa todo en conjunto. El problema viene dado por las credenciales necesarias para acceder a los servicios de AWS. Tengo dudas respecto a de que manera conformar el "Dockerfile". Espero haberme explicado bien, saludos..

Comment: Puedes usar un dokerfile o usar una imagen limpia para cargar lo que necesites, es como instalar un Linux y dejar todo configurado, después le sacas una captura al doker y lo distribuyes. Yo uso doker-compose

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Por el momento estoy ejecutando un Dockerfile que configuré siguiendo las instrucciones en la documentación oficial, para Docker y Python. Me encuentro con un error de credenciales.  botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials ese error me arroja

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297172/boto3-error-botocore-exceptions-nocredentialserror-unable-to-locate-credential

Comment: Gracias, ahora mismo sigo ese hilo de conversación..

Comment: *Pueden sugerirme material de referencia?* No, nosotros no damos recomendaciones de recursos externos. Te recomiendo quitar esa parte de la pregunta. Pues pedir esas recomendaciones es motivo de cierre.

Comment: @Dante S. Gracias por enseñarme, voy aprendiendo día a día. Ahora modifico esa parte de la pregunta en cuestión.

Comment: De nada Ema Avalos c:

Answer (score 0):

Docker no es más que un mecanismo que permite crear instantáneas de un software. Estas instantáneas se pueden desplegar en diferentes máquinas rápida y cómodamente.

Lo que tienes ahora mismo serán dos Lambdas con el código python escrito tal cual. El cambio que te están solicitando consiste en encapsular el código y sus dependencias en un contenedor docker para simplificar el despliegue del servicio.

Un contenedor docker es independiente del entorno en el que lo estés ejecutando. El contenedor es una especie de sistema virtual estanco (no del todo, pero como definición inicial nos sirve), en el cual tu "instalas" un software determinado. Una vez el contenedor está creado, puedes recrear el entorno que contiene en prácticamente cualquier máquina simplemente desplegando una copia del contenedor que acabas de crear.

Es decir, tu tarea consiste en varios pasos, siendo el primero de ellos el crear un par de contenedores docker que contengan el código python de cada Lambda, así como todas las dependencias necesarias.

A continuación deberías subir estos contenedores a sendos repositorios de ECR. Te sugiero etiquetar las versiones que subas para permitir su identificación

Finalmente debes reemplazar las Lambdas actuales por otras que en vez de ejecutar python carguen y ejecuten una copia de las imágenes que acabas de subir a ECR.

Existen varios tutoriales sobre cómo realizar esta tarea. Una simple búsqueda en Internet te debería permitir dar con ellos